# Is there a closed-form expression for a product of two basis elements in arbitrary Cayley-Dickson algebras?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am investigating multiplication rules of various numbers: $\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{C}, \mathbb{Q}, \mathbb{O}$.
All these have tables specifying the products of basis elements, ex: for Quaternions these are products between: $1, i, j, k$.

**My question is:**
How do I construct such a table for Sedonions and higher (ex: for an algebra of a dimension of 128)?

#### EDIT

We know the multiplication formula for the CD construction as:
$(a,b)(c,d) = (ac - d^*b, da + bc^*)$

One idea I just got from another colleague is a recursive construction:

1. Start from $\mathbb{R}$, the basis element is $e_0 = 1$. We have $1 \times 1 = 1$ and $1^* = 1$.
2. The basis for $\mathbb{C}$ is $\{e_0, e_1\}$ but that could be also written as: $\{(e_0, 0), (0, e_0)\}$. For such a representation we may apply the pair multiplication formula. We could get ex: $e_1 \times e_1 = (-e_0, 0) = -1$.
3. Recursively construct all multiplication tables by expressing basis elements of an (n+1)-dimensional algebra as pairs of basis elements from a (n)-dimensional algebra. Calculate all products as above.

I think the above solution makes sense but I was initially looking for a closed-form expression for the product of 2 arbitrary chosen basis elements in a very high dimensional algebra **without** constructing the whole tables...

Comment: How would you construct sedenions without Cayley-Dickson?